# I want to change my xml file into xsl so that it can fit into my chart, I am trying to put it into ascending form…

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to change my xml file into xsl so that it can fit into my chart, I am trying to put it into ascending form…
This is my .xml

```
<chart>
    <set label='UOB' value='420000' />
    <set label='UOB' value='910000' />
    <set label='DBS' value='720000' />
    <set label='OCBC' value='550000' />
    <set label='UOB' value='810000' />
    <set label='DBS' value='510000' />
    <set label='OCBC' value='680000' />
    <set label='UOB' value='620000' />
    <set label='DBS' value='610000' />
    <set label='OCBC' value='490000' />
    <set label='OCBC' value='530000' />
    <set label='DBS' value='330000' />
</chart>
```

Can someone help me make it into xsl ascending form please?

Thank you...
Please reply me ^^

Comment: What is your "chart"? By which means would you like your xml sorted and converted to xslt?

Comment: a column chart.. it'll be from excel --> xml --> xsl --> chart

Answer (score 0):

This stylesheet will order your `<set>` elements by the `value` atrribute:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
                <xsl:sort select="@value"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The template (an identity transform) is called recursively. It copies each element and its attributes to the result tree. The `select` atribute in `<xsl:sort>` contains a relative XPath expression selecting the node that will be used in the sorting.

The default order is `ascending`.

Comment: It works with the example you posted. Copy your source and paste it here: http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html and also the above stylesheet, and you will see that it works. If your source is different from the one you posted, it may not be working for another reason.

Comment: Thanks! helderdarocha, but unfortunely, it doesn't work on my chart T__T i don't know how and why.....

Comment: Why don't you post your full example, then?

Comment: This is the XSL...
http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=Pk9pucEs

I am using Visual Studio and Chrome for browsing...

Comment: Oh and I am writing in .aspx

Comment: OK! I've tried with this http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=T5bQb14N

now, when I refresh my banks.aspx, it is blank.. but when I check the source code, it is everything i wanted!! can anyone help me? btw, my chart is in .swf ... 
Thanks

Comment: Your XML source is not well-formed. This code is very simple. It's no use posting links here. Nobody will read them. Create a new question and include all the code relevant to your question. And spend some time trying to find a solution your self. Look for a XML tutorial so you'll understand the basics before sending a question.